# Click and drag won't give focus to Finder window

Tags: finder, mojave

Lately I've been noticing that my machine seems a bit slow or unresponsive to click events. For example, when using Chrome or whatever and then clicking a Finder window in the background, it took me 2-3 tries before that window gains focus.

Just today I realized that it's "my" fault. Very often when I click an unfocused Finder window, I do it swiftly and it does not gain focus. I can reproduce that behaviour now by click+dragging. Even the slightest drag when clicking makes this happen. I don't think this is how it behaved in previous versions and I think it's wrong.

In short, Finder windows won't gain focus when click+dragging. I just tested on 10.14 and I can't reproduce it. I'm running 10.14.3

Is there a setting I can tweak to go back?

Comment: Hey @IconDaemon, isn't macOS version relevant?

Comment: You have the Mojave tag set at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Cool. In this particular case tho, a couple minor versions back the issue is gone. Just edited the question adding that.